# How to debug 404 errors in Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to make a simple web server for some files. I thought that would be Express, but apparently Express isn't very good at communicating with the developper.

I use this code:

```
app.use("/pypyjs-0.4.0/", express.static(__dirname + "/../../pypyjs-0.4.0/"));
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname+"/web"));
```

I get 404 error for any of the files in `/pypyjs-0.4.0/`. I tried all kinds of combinations. I also try to comment out the `"/"` serve code.

The **real problem here** - and the topic of this question - however, isn't some mistake in using `app.use`, but the fact that upon 404 error, I get this output in browser:

```
Cannot GET /pypyjs-0.4.0/package.json
```

And this in console:

> 

(yes, there's nothing there)

When I used any other web server, it usually did print what was requested of it and which paths were searched when 404 or other error occured. I did a google search for this for express and I found nothing.

So how do I get some info on where is Express searching for the files and why did it fail?

Comment: Just a little unclear, what uri you using in browser `/pypyjs-0.4.0/` or `/ddd/package.json` ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I accidentally mixed two tests I did in this question. I'll edit.

Comment: I believe this should be working based upon what code you have provided. The only red flag I see is that you should use the native `path` module to generate urls..

`const path = require('path')
path.resolve(__dirname, 'web')
path.resolve(__dirname, '../../pypyjs-0.4.0/')
`